# numerical keypad of my laptop not working

Tags: 16.04

I just migrated to ubuntu 16.04 LTS, everything is fine except my laptop numerical keypad is not working. Please help me. It's Fujitsu Life book A series laptop

Comment: Check the 'NumLock' key, it locks/unlocks the numerical keypad. Also try: 'Shift+NumLock'.

Answer (score 3):

I have Same problem in Ubuntu 16.04. I solved it by changing this setting:

**Settings >> Universal Access >> Pointing and Clicking >> Mouse Keys
Turn it Off**

Answer (score 0):

Open your terminal and use the command xev to see if the keys are responsive, if you press a number and there isn't a response on screen this means that ubuntu isn't recognizing the keys so you'll have to find a way to enable them, theres a few threads here explaining how to enable unresponsive keys.

Comment: please suggest in little bit detail, I am new to ubuntu

Comment: @aleem You'll want to open the terminal and run the command xev, this should bring up a bunch of key codes. press one of the keys that arent working on your keypad and if a new code comes up that means ubuntu recognizes the key but isn't responding to it. In that case you may want to post another question. If there is no new output when the keys are pressed that means they are not compatible and you'll have to either as here or search online for a driver/python script to enable them.